# G and G complement both have perfect matchings

Tags: graph-theory

What can we say about graphs G such that G and G' (G complement) both contain a perfect matching?

For examples, even cycles have the property: pairing vertices (v1,v2),(v3,v4),...,(n-1,n) gives a matching in G and pairing "antipodal" vertices gives a matching in G'.

Comment: Any self-complementary graph with an even number of vertices has a perfect matching — and so does its complement!

Answer (score 1):

To generalize the cycles, any vertex-transitive graph on an even number of vertices that is connected and complement-connected has this property.